# font attributes in specialcomment inside newenvironment

Tags: formatting, comments

I do not manage to set the font attributes of a special comment (comment package) command inside a custom new environment. In the MWE example, I'd like the text within `enonce` to be blue(black) when `wans` is true(false), and the text within `answer` to be red.

Thanks for the help,

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newbool{wans}
\booltrue{wans}
%\boolfalse{wans}

\newenvironment{enonce}{\ifbool{wans}{\itshape\color{blue}}{\normalfont\color{black}}}{}
\specialcomment{answer}{\begingroup\normalfont\color{red}}{\endgroup}

\ifbool{wans}{\includecomment{answer}}{\excludecomment{answer}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enonce}
\begin{itemize}     

\item[Q1] \lipsum[1]    
\begin{answer}          
\lipsum[1]      
\end{answer}

\item[Q2] \lipsum[1]    
\begin{answer}          
\lipsum[1]      
\end{answer}

\end{itemize}  
\end{enonce}

\end{document}

enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the documentation:

> With \specialcomment you do *not* have to do an additional 
>   \includecomment{smalltt}

so you must enable the comment like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newbool{wans}
\booltrue{wans}
%\boolfalse{wans}

\newenvironment{enonce}{\ifbool{wans}{\itshape\color{blue}}{\normalfont\color{black}}}{}

\ifbool{wans}{\specialcomment{answer}{\begingroup\normalfont\color{red}}{\endgroup}}{\excludecomment{answer}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enonce}
\begin{itemize}

\item[Q1] \lipsum[1]
\begin{answer}
\lipsum[1]
\end{answer}

\item[Q2] \lipsum[1]
\begin{answer}
\lipsum[1]
\end{answer}

\end{itemize}
\end{enonce}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without package `etoolbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newif\ifwans 
\wansfalse
%\wanstrue

\newenvironment{enonce}
  {\ifwans \itshape\color{blue}\else\normalfont\normalcolor\fi}
  {}   
\ifwans
  \specialcomment{answer}{\begingroup\normalfont\color{red}}{\endgroup}%
\else \excludecomment{answer}%
\fi    
\begin{document}        
\begin{enonce}
    \begin{itemize}

            \item[Q1] \lipsum[1]
            \begin{answer}
                \lipsum[1]
            \end{answer}

            \item[Q2] \lipsum[1]
            \begin{answer}
                \lipsum[1]
            \end{answer}

        \end{itemize}
\end{enonce}        
\end{document}
```